# Xbox 360 power supply has red light at start of day

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

The adapter has a red light when we turn the power on at the mains. When it's not connected to the Xbox, it will be orange until we plug it in.

Since this happens at the start, it's not an overheating problem.

After we reset the power at the main enough times, the power does work, and it does not fail as long as we don't turn off the console.

Has anyone ever had this problem and/or know if a new power supply will fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906101) lists three reasons why you might get a red light:

> - There is too much current.
> - The voltage is too high.
> - The temperature of the power supply is too high.

You say it happens straight away so that rules out #3.

Have you tried it in a different socket?

If that still fails then you might have to go for Solution 4: Order a replacement.

If the power supply works in a different socket then you need to get your electrics checked. There might be a problem with that socket.

Comment: thanks, the microsoft page kept giving me a too busy so i opted to ask here :)

Answer (score 2):

if you phone the xbox help line they will send you a new power brick for free, the guy on the phone said it was a problem with the power suply and nothing to do with the xbox 360 it self

Comment: thanks, i'll keep this in mind if it fully breaks. we traded charge and play cables and it works fine now though.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of it all was the charge and play adapter. now that probably means something similar too get a new adapter, it was funny that all i have to do is unplug the charge and play, start the xbox and plug it back in for it to work.